# No instance for (Num (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of syntactic negation

Tags: haskell, recursion, partial-application

I have written the following Haskell code to return the primary and secondary diagonal of [[Int]]

```
getDiagonal' :: [[Int]] -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> [Int]
getDiagonal' [] _ _ = []
getDiagonal' (x:xs) i fn = i' : getDiagonal' xs (fn i) fn
  where i' = head $ drop i x

getPrimaryDiagonal :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
getPrimaryDiagonal x = getDiagonal' x 0 (+1)

getSecondaryDiagonal :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
getSecondaryDiagonal x = getDiagonal' x ((length x) - 1) (+(-1))
```

However, I would have thought that the final line could be the following, using `(-)` the same way as `(+)`

```
getSecondaryDiagonal x = getDiagonal' x ((length x) - 1) (-1)
```

However, that does not work, when I do that I get

```
Main.hs:27:59: error:
    • No instance for (Num (Int -> Int))
        arising from a use of syntactic negation
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the third argument of ‘getDiagonal'’, namely ‘(- 1)’
      In the expression: getDiagonal' x ((length x) - 1) (- 1)
      In an equation for ‘getSecondaryDiagonal’:
          getSecondaryDiagonal x = getDiagonal' x ((length x) - 1) (- 1)
```

Why does `(-)` produce that error?

Comment: No this is the only exception, this is interpreted as minus 1, not `\x -> (-) x 1`.

Comment: Ultimately, this is caused by our standard mathematical notation, which makes us write `1/x` for the reciprocal (and NOT `/x`) but `-x` for the opposite (and NOT `0-x`, which is correct but uncommon). This is a bit inconsistent, but there's little we can do about that. Haskell decided to allow sections `(op expr)` which coped with the unary minus, so it was decided to allow an exception for `-x`, and add `subtract` and `negate` to the `Prelude`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(-1)` is interpreted as *negative one*, it is, as far as I know, the only exception that is made for operators that are non-binary. `(-1)` is thus not a function that subtracts one away.

You can make use of [**`subtract :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:subtract)  for this:

```
getSecondaryDiagonal x = getDiagonal' x ((length x) - 1) (subtract 1)
```

or you can use [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip)  which is how `subtract` is implemented:

```
getSecondaryDiagonal x = getDiagonal' x ((length x) - 1) (flip (-) 1)
```

Comment: The other function sometimes needed for this weird behavior of `(-)` sections is `negate`, useful when you need unary negation as a function value rather than immediately applying it to a literal number.